# How to refresh current Activity every 10 second?

Tags: java, android, xml

i have problem with my project Android Studio. Can you help me how to create auto refresh current activity every 10 second without button click?

Comment: you  need to show your code to let us know what exactly you are trying

Comment: I didn't have the code. Please show me code for create auto refresh the activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask doTask = new TimerTask() {       
    @Override
    public void run() {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            public void run() { 
               try {
                    Intent intent = getIntent();
                    finish();
                    startActivity(intent);
                   }
             catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
timer.schedule(doTask, 0, "Your time 10 minute");
```

Comment: Thanks. its work and very helpfull :)

Comment: glad to hear that .. please vote up this answer

Comment: Hi, how to stop this timer with stop button?

Comment: You can also just call `recreate()` inside the `run()`-block.

Answer (score 0):

Use Timer for background running just use Service to get the activity auto refresh for every 10 seconds. https://www.journaldev.com/amp